# used SetUnhandledExceptionFilter but corresponding method was not called

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I've used `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` to install custom exception handler. In the code below I expect that if unhandled exception is occured than `UnhandledException` method is called and `foo!` is printed

```
namespace mcFastNative {

Receiver* incOrdersA;
IncFeed* incOrders;

Receiver* snpOrdersA;
SnapshotFeed* snpOrders;

    // not important methods are ommited

bool McFastNativeAdapter::Disconnect() {
    incOrdersA->Disconnect();
    return true;
}


LONG WINAPI UnhandledException(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo)  
{  
    printf("foo!");
            return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void McFastNativeAdapter::Initialize(unsigned long feedA_group, unsigned long feedA_source, int feedA_port,
    unsigned long historicalIp, int historicalPort,
    unsigned long snapshotGroup, unsigned long snapshotSource, int snapshotPort)
{
    // Init WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &data );

    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledException);

    incOrdersA = new Receiver(feedA_group, feedA_source, feedA_port);
    snpOrdersA = new Receiver(snapshotGroup, snapshotSource, snapshotPort);

    incOrders = new IncFeed("IncFeed");
    incOrdersA->SetFeed(incOrders);

    snpOrders = new SnapshotFeed("SnapshotFeed");
    snpOrdersA->SetFeed(snpOrders);
}

}
```

But I've received such output:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has
 thrown an exception.
   at mcFastNative.McFastNativeAdapter.Disconnect()
   at Fast.mcFastAdapterCpp.Disconnect() ...`

`foo!` was not printed to console however as you can see exception occured. Why unhandled exception in `incOrdersA->Disconnect();` was not catched and `foo!` was not printed?

Comment: It looks like it wasn't an unhandled exception and there was an exception handler installed outside of your `McFastNativeAdapter` code.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze i only have CLI wrapper around that class and than everything goes to C#. I have custom handler in C# but i'm not sure if it applies to native code...

Comment: Oh, I think your C# code is installing exception handlers around calls into native code or just as the first thing. So, there's no chance for this exception to be truly unhandled.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze i just disabled c# handler and still can not see `foo!` printed, so it seems it is not because of c# handler.